# pr-predestroy script not running heroku

Tags: heroku

I have been unable to find a way to debug whether a `pr-predestroy` heroku script has run.

How do I view/debug the `pr-predestroy` script which is defined in the `app.json`?

I am able to manually run the script using `heroku run ./manage.py my-script --app app-here`.

Related:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#pr-predestroy-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pr-predestroy` script runs when review apps are destroyed once the associated pull request is merged or closed. Logs of a `pr-predestroy` scrips are not available to customers because the app gets deleted.

However, customers need to contact Heroku Support - https://help.heroku.com/ for help obtaining the output.

Comment: Thanks Raman for your help in heroku support. I hope the feature is added in the future. Cheers.